# Sort tuples by time interval? Python

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

How can I sort these tuples by time interval, say every hour?

```
 [('172.18.74.146', datetime.time(11, 28, 58)), ('10.227.211.244',
 datetime.time(11, 54, 19)), ('10.227.215.68', datetime.time(11, 54, 34)),
 ('10.227.209.139', datetime.time(12, 14, 47)), ('10.227.147.98',
 datetime.time(14, 47, 25))]
```

The result should be:

```
    [["172.18.74.146, 10.227.211.244, 10.227.215.68", "11-12"], etc...]
```

I tried to use group by, but doesnt get what I want:

```
   for dd in data[1:]:
    ips = dd[1].split(",")
    dates = dd[2].split(",")
    i = 0
    while(i < len(dates)):
        ips[i] = ips[i].strip()
        hour, mins, second = dates[i].strip().split(":")
        dates[i] = datetime.time(int(hour), int(mins), int(second))
        i+=1    
    order = [(k, ', '.join(str(s[0]) for s in v)) for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(ips, dates), key=operator.itemgetter(1)), lambda x: x[1].hour)]
```

Comment: Is the missing comma after `datetime.time(11, 54, 34))` intentional?

Comment: @AIG no sorry about that, I fixed it.

Comment: @Ben, there's a problem with the other answers. I'm writing one up now, but I wanted to check; is that really the output you want, as opposed to something like `[('11-12', ('172.18.74.146', '10.227.211.244', '10.227.215.68')), etc...]`?

Comment: @Cyphase I would like [("11-12", then the count of the number of IP's so 3)), etc..]  If possible how do it every half hour too.

Comment: @Ben, so for your data above, you want `[('11-12', 3), ('12-13', 1), ('14-15', 1)]`?

Comment: @Ben, and what should the `'11-12'` part look like for half hours?

Comment: For example it would be [(11-1130, 1), (1130-12, 2), etc..] @Cyphase

Comment: @Ben, that's easy enough I suppose, but are you sure that's the best output for whatever you're going to do with it?

Comment: @Cyphase what output would you suggest, I mean it could just be IP and could get the count, but how would I make it a half hour? by the min

Comment: It really depends on how you're going to be using it, but at the very least I would only include the start of the hour/half-hour. Meaning, `11` instead of `'11-12'`, and `11.5` instead of `'11-1130'`. How are you using those values?

Comment: @Cyphase woops yea I meant it should be [(11-11.5, 1), (11.5-12, 1)...etc] I just need it broken down by half hour.  When I tried to change x[1].hour to x[1].min it is broken down weird and now I need to use date time interval?

Comment: @Ben, first of all, that would have to be a string; they way you're writing it, it's a subtraction that's always going to be negative. Second, why do you need the end time specified like that, as opposed to just knowing each time refers to the next half-hour?

Comment: @cyphase I dont need them specified like that, I just need the break down by half hour Ill update it to the code I have.

Comment: @Ben, I guess I was overthinking that :P. Hold on.

Comment: @Ben, answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import datetime
import itertools


def iter_len(iterable):
    return sum(1 for __ in iterable)


def by_hour(item):  # Hour key
    timestamp = item[1]
    return '{}-{}'.format(timestamp.hour, (timestamp.hour+1) % 24)


def by_half_hour(item):  # Half-hour key
    timestamp = item[1]
    half_hour = timestamp.hour + (0.5 * (timestamp.minute // 30))
    return '{:.1f}-{:.1f}'.format(half_hour, (half_hour+0.5) % 24)


def get_results(data, key):  # Name this more appropriately
    data = sorted(data, key=key)
    for key, grouper in itertools.groupby(data, key):
        yield (key, iter_len(grouper))


data = [
    ('172.18.74.146', datetime.time(11, 28, 58)),
    ('10.227.211.244', datetime.time(11, 54, 19)),
    ('10.227.215.68', datetime.time(11, 54, 34)),
    ('10.227.209.139', datetime.time(12, 14, 47)),
    ('10.227.147.98', datetime.time(14, 47, 25)),
    ]

print('By Hour')
print(list(get_results(data, by_hour)))
print()
print("By Half Hour")
print(list(get_results(data, by_half_hour)))
```

Output:

```
$ ./SO_32081251.py 
By Hour
[('11-12', 3), ('12-13', 1), ('14-15', 1)]

By Half Hour
[('11.0-11.5', 1), ('11.5-12.0', 2), ('12.0-12.5', 1), ('14.5-15.0', 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

```
In [17]: a = [('172.18.74.146', datetime.time(11, 28, 58)), ('10.227.211.244',
 datetime.time(11, 54, 19)), ('10.227.215.68', datetime.time(11, 54, 34)),
 ('10.227.209.139', datetime.time(12, 14, 47)), ('10.227.147.98',
 datetime.time(14, 47, 25))]

In [18]: [(k, ', '.join(str(s[0]) for s in v)) for k, v in groupby(a, lambda x: x[1].hour)]
Out[18]: 
[(11, '172.18.74.146, 10.227.211.244, 10.227.215.68'),
 (12, '10.227.209.139'),
 (14, '10.227.147.98')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is almost what you want. Use the hour to group by:

```
for k,g in itertools.groupby(order, lambda x: x[1].hour):
    print k,list(g)
```

Results in:

```
11 [('172.18.74.146', datetime.time(11, 28, 58)), ('10.227.211.244', datetime.time(11, 54, 19)), ('10.227.215.68', datetime.time(11, 54, 34))]
12 [('10.227.209.139', datetime.time(12, 14, 47))]
14 [('10.227.147.98', datetime.time(14, 47, 25))]
```

Comment: and if I wanted to change it to half hour? Would it be lamda x: (x[1].hour / 2)? @Randy C